# Is it possible to design an amplifier with a given gain from a random discrete JFET?

Tags: specifications, production, jfet

A few weeks ago, I played around with a discrete JFET bass preamp design I found online (http://www.albertkreuzer.com/preamp.htm).

[image: pre-amplifier schematic]

One thing I realized from analyzing the circuit, running simulations and eventually building the amplifier was that performance, and even actual operation in some cases, relied heavily on the characteristics of the specific transistors used.

In my research, I found that all JFET manufacturers provide only crude tolerances for specs like VgsOff or Isat. As an exercise, I tried to come up with an amplifier design that would deliver a specific gain over the whole range of spec, but failed. JFETs just vary too much, and a given circuit could very likely break if a specific transistor had to be replaced. In my case, I ended up having to test several transistors and adapt the design to the resulting specific specs.

A good production design wouldn't require this kind of cherry picking. Have I missed anything ? Is there a good way to design a circuit with transistors that have big tolerance on key specs ?

Comment: What was the amplifier circuit you "come up with" that "failed". I'm going to defend the JFET corner and ask for your design so I might be able to see where things went wrong. I've seen several mass-produced circuits using JFETs and can't believe they are so flaky. Designed a couple too and never had production problems.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem unique to JFETs. The BJT's current gain (\$h_{fe}\$) varies over a large range, perhaps from 50 to 200. MOSFETs have a highly variable gate threshold voltage. I have a 2N7000 datasheet here that specifies \$V_{GS(th)}\$ as 0.8V to 3V.

In all cases, the solution to coping with this variation is *negative feedback*. This takes some fraction of the output and feeds it back to cancel some of the input, reducing the gain. This means the variability in the transistor's gain is divided by the proportion of negative feedback. This makes the circuit more predictable. It also reduces non-linear distortion by a similar amount.

In single-transistor circuits (all kinds, MOSFET, JFET, BJT), a common way to introduce negative feedback is to put a resistor in the emitter/source, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV4mmE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the input signal goes up, the current in the load resistors (R2, R3, R5) increases, bringing the output signal down (these are inverting amplifiers). But also, that current must flow in the feedback resistors (R1, R4, R6), which must raise the voltage across them, which reduces the drive provided by the input signal. The gain becomes more a function of the ratio of the two resistors than it does the particular parameters of the transistor, to the extent that the net gain (after negative feedback) is less than the transistor's maximum gain.

You can see in your schematic, R5, R10, and R25 are analogous to R1, R4, and R6 in my schematic. Ideally the biasing is such that at the DC Q point, the transistor half-way between full-on and full-off. That is, the output is in the middle of the supply rails. This way, you have the maximum headroom in both directions before clipping. You can adjust the biasing with a trimpot to this optimal point. Or, you can not adjust it, and design your circuit such that given the minimum and maximum parameters for your transistors, you may have less headroom, but you still have enough, even at the extremes.

If you can make a circuit that has a whole ton of gain, so much that it can be considered infinite, then the Q point is effectively defined only by the negative feedback. You might also get a very linear amplifier, since the non-linearities are divided by the (very large) gain of the circuit.

Well, there is such a circuit: the [operational amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier). Professional audio engineers don't have the fear of op-amps that musicians do, so it's likely that a professional design that was intended to be produced without need for any trim-pot adjustment would just use op-amps.

You can also make an op-amp with discrete JFETs, if you are allergic to op-amps. An op-amp, at it's core, is a [differential pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier#Configurations). Here's a simple one with BJTs, although with appropriate biasing, it works with JFETs also:

[image: schematic]

In fact, [it even works with vacuum tubes](http://www.freewebs.com/valvewizard/acltp.html) (valves), and [the first op-amps were made with tubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Historical_timeline).

Comment: Yes, but your edit to the OP's question shows the schematic for a Vgs(off) test circuit and *not* the schematic for the pre-amp (which does have negative feedback) .... unless the OP *built* the wrong circuit!

Comment: @MikeJ-UK good point. I didn't read it that carefully. Looking back, I can't find a schematic on the page referenced. Maybe the OP or someone else can edit it in properly.

Comment: It was in a link at the top of the page. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of negative feedback.
Negative feedback achieves defined gain by providing vastly more than is needed (notionally infinite) and then feeding back output signal to input in antiphase in such a way that when the required gain is achieved the gain is stable.

Searching for something like
   amplifier feedback
 of jfet amplifier feedback
will find much quality material (and much rubbish :-) )

A reasonable introduction here - [The Common Source JFET Amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_3.html) . Cct below is from that page.

[image]

---

[FET small signal analysis](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/46705000/Chapter-2-FET-Small-Signal-Analysis) 50 page slieshow with perhaps enough detail to be useful coutesy of the dreaed DoCStock. EE dept of KUKTEM (Malaysia) - may be findable elsewhere.

[Useful](http://www.next.gr/video/amplifiers/) - mainly video amps but some good material.

[Lots of starter material here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=jfet+amplifier+feedback&sa=X&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=JhS3Udv8L4uaiQec7oDwCw&ved=0CEoQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=720)

[SPICE simulations](http://www.audiohobby.com/)

[May be useful - Circuit workbook with basic solutions](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/jfetamp.html) Question 5 relates. Others potentially useful.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to the problem is to exploit the JFET for its high gate impedance, and not try to make it amplify at all. That is to say, use it as a source follower, completely swamped with negative feedback.

An example of this is the input stage of the ADA MP-1 guitar pre-amp, which also shows another technique:

[image]

(Actual transistor part numbers are not as shown.)   Here, Q7 and Q6 form what looks very similar to a complementary feedback pair (Sziklai pair), except that it's between a JFET and BJT. That is to say, you can imagine R86, Q7 and Q6 to be a single three-terminal transistor device.

Simulating this with LTSpice, I found that most of the JFET models can be substituted and it performs well.  This is not the case any more if Q6 is removed. Then the stage can no longer transfer the same large signal swings as before, particularly if we reduce the load to 10 kOhm or less, and the performance varies more with the JFET model.